Ubuntu UI freezes sometimes on a half up window maximize state
I don't have a precise reproduction, but I can get it to happen almost every time after a few seconds/minutes by:

maximize any window, e.g. Text Editor
press on its menu bar on the top on the laptop touchscreen
while holding my finger down while selecting the menu bar, move it up and down slightly a few times

I should also mention that sometimes instead of reproducing I instead reach a similar looking state with the semi-maximized window  up UI but from which I can recover because the mouse still moves but and I can finish manually maximizing the window in quesiton. This is separate but closely related state to the freeze I described above, from which I don't know how to recover.
I've hit this several times, and when it happens. I can move the mouse cursor around, but clicking with it doesn't seem to do anything anymore to the UI, and the keyboard also seems to have no effect, e.g. Alt + Tab does not work. The only way I know how to move forward is to reboot.
I think I've managed to make this happen without the touchscreen as well, but it is way harder to reproduce that way.
Are there any known bug reports/workaround for this?
Ubuntu 24.04, Lenovo ThinkPad P14s AMD running accelerated X11 (because the default Wayland was too buggy for other reasons).


I'm running P14s AMD with Debian testing for two years without problems. Try to check if GNOME is the culprit, since I'm using Xfce with X11. (Xubuntu Live USB for a check)(I do not have a touchscreen, though)
